# Issue bootstraping juju 2.0 on maas xenial setup

Tags: juju, maas

Trying to bootstrap juju on my maas set up, my physical no is aquired it fails after that. Can't figure out what to do

```
rama@Maas:~$ juju bootstrap maas maas/172.17.6.253 --to snoutlike-ute.maas --show-log
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:60 running juju [2.0-beta6 gc go1.6.1]
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO cmd cmd.go:141 cloud "maas" not found, trying as a provider name
Creating Juju controller "local.maas" on maas/172.17.6.253
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:482 combined bootstrap constraints:
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.network network.go:327 setting prefer-ipv6 to false
Bootstrapping model "admin"
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:90 looking for bootstrap tools: version=2.0-beta6
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:106 finding tools in stream "devel"
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:108 reading tools with major.minor version 2.0
2016-04-30 17:45:19 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:116 filtering tools by version: 2.0-beta6
Starting new instance for initial controller
Launching instance
2016-04-30 17:45:20 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:22 destroying model "admin"
2016-04-30 17:45:20 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:33 destroying instances
2016-04-30 17:45:20 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:686 error cleaning up: destroying instances: machine 0: blockdevice blockdevice 2.0 schema check failed: model: expected string, got nothing
2016-04-30 17:45:20 ERROR cmd supercommand.go:448 failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: cannot run instances: cannot run instance: blockdevice 5: blockdevice 2.0 schema check failed: model: expected string, got nothing
```

Comment: Have you tried recommissioning the bootstrap node?

Comment: Oh thanks this did the trick. But now how can I be sure that my storage are kept  ? this provisionning takes sda

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, do you mean the data on your storage of bootstrap node?

Comment: My maas server setup was made to take in account all my hdds on my servers. But juju doesn't seem to "like" that as I have to re-commision the node for juju to be abble to  provision it. In my rack I have 16 servers with different setup: 2 ssd, 4 ssd 4ssd + 30 HDD

Answer (score 1):

Juju's support for MAAS 2.0 (which is what you'll get in Xenial) is still in development. The bug you're seeing appears to be fixed for Juju 2.0-beta7:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1576368

Comment: Hi axw, Thanks for the feedback, so recommandation is not to go maas 2.0 / xenial to work with juju ?

Comment: @DavidRamahefason Both MAAS and Juju are still leading up to their 2.0 releases for 16.04, it's close but as you can see there's still a few issues to still iron out.

Comment: @JorgeCastro thanks for your answer. So far I gave up as I can't figure out how to tell juju to accept my partitions. Got errors if other than sda or sdb (tried md0, vg0 with no success). Juju GUI doesn't get the hardware infos, and in cli I only see cpu/mem no hdd space but it might be normal. Tried 1.9 maas/juju 1.25 and 2.0 maas and 2.0 juju